# In a CNN, how to view the weights of multiple filters?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to get a better understanding of CNNs and so I am using keras to basically make a small CNN and want to go through the calculations by hand.

I downloaded the images from the GTSRB database, then using `PIL` library package converted the image set to greyscale and resized to (6 x 6).

The code below shows the CNN I've created.
It includes 1 convolution layer (with 2 filters of size 2x2), 1 max pooling layer (2x2), a flattening layer and a dense layer at the end.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(2, kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu', input_shape=(6,6,1)))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(sign_label_list),activation='relu'))
```

I then trained the network and saved the model and weights.

I read online that for checking the weights (`h5` file type), I need a tool to view the weights. So I downloaded `HDFView` tool.

Now I am trying to view the weights for each of the filters, but I can only see the weights of 1 of the filters.

[Filter weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaulG.png)

How would I get the weights of both the filters?

Does anyone know if there is a way to view the weights through python?

Originally, I wanted to test with only 1 filter but I get `nan` when I view the weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation and Keras FAQ [found here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/).

The suggested way to view weights for a particular layer is to do this:

```
weights,biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

I then printed the weights to the console using `print(weights)` and this displayed the values of all filters.

However, I still had trouble viewing the weights of multiple filters using the `HDFView` tool.